# Linear falloff for bone envelopes

Tags: bones

by default in both blender and 3ds max there is a curve in the falloff of the envelope but in max there is a way to switch to linear, how to do this in blender? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've found reference to the falloff being quadratic - but nothing anywhere to indicate that it can be changed. You could post it as a feature request at https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/